# Использование баз данный в учебных проектах

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Всем привет!

Когда я учился в универе, в проектах я использовал универовский сервак для работы с базой данных и бед не знал. Сейчас, как говорится, ушел в свободное плаванье и начал создавать всякие мелкие проекты для оттачивания навыков. И вот назрел вопрос: **как создать свою базу данных? Есть ли какой-то бесплатный сервер, для пользования?**

Работаю я на маке, скачал пару приложений, но нельзя (бесплатно) использовать их сервер, а подключиться к localhost не получается.

Собственно и всё. Как мне создать базу данных для использования ее в проектах точно так же, как используют свои базы данных различные разработчики в реальных проектах?

Comment: Сайт где будет размещен? Правильно, на сервере. Что мешает на этом же сервере (если не дает хостинг), поставить еще и базу?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Хорошее предложение, но тут то и главный смысл моего замечания, что проекты учебные. Я сайт нигде размещать не буду. Я его просто создам... Да. Таким способом я просто оттачиваю навыки и разбираюсь в различных паттернах и алгоритмах. А опубликовывать сайт я пока не планирую

Comment: Учебный или нет, смысла не меняет. Хотите базу, ставьте, в чем проблема то? Не хотите поднимать сервер у себя на компе, берите SQLite, LiteDB и аналоги, где будет один файлик.

Comment: Это вот такое сейчас университетское образование? Мда... / База данных - понятие растяжимое и очень общее. Простой текстовый файл - уже база данных. / Вероятно, вам нужна Система Управления Базой Данных (СУБД). Sql Server - одна из них. Нужна бесплатная СУБД, смотрите в сторону PostgreSQL, MySql, MariaDB, Firebird, sqlite. Кстати, это всё _реляционные_ СУБД. Возможно, вам нужна NoSql? / Сервер - понятие опять таки слишком общее. Что именно вы подразумеваете под этим словом? Веб-сервер, application server, client-server architecture (я ещё много умных слов знаю)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть ряд решений для легкого поднимания локального веб-сервера прямо на своей машине. Например WAMP - https://www.wampserver.com/en/

Еще есть Open Server, Denwer, Laragon, XAMPP, UwAmp, Vertrigo и черт знает что еще ибо вариантов слишком много

Ставишь и чуть ли не в один клик все настраивается. По ходу необходимости меняешь настройки под себя изменяя ту или иную конфигурацию сервера. Там же будет сразу как на хостинге доступен phpMyAdmin, настройки пхп и много другого.

Вобщем, покупать сервер не обязательно. Как и настраивать вручную весь сервер, собственно, тоже.

---

На маке тоже есть свои вебсервера "из коробки". MAMP ,MNPP, и еще куча вариантов.

---

На крайний случай всегда можно воспользоваться SQLite